# Enable checkbox Delegated approver

Tags: approval-process

In approval process i need to select checkbox for Delegated approver but i am not able to see this option when i open existing approval process for an custom object Promotions. could any one help me on this what might be the reason and how to enable it

Thanks
Naga

Answer (score -1):

In order to see it you need to enable it.

**Change Your Approval User Preferences**

- From your personal settings, enter Approver Settings in the Quick Find box, then select Approver Settings. No results? Enter Personal Information in the Quick Find box, then select Personal Information.
- Optionally, select your Delegated Approver.
- Optionally, enter your Manager.
- Set your preference for receiving approval request emails. This preference also affects whether you receive approval request notifications in Salesforce1. The options are:
- If I am an approver or delegated approver Only if I am an approver
  Only if I am a delegated approver Never—If you select this option,
  you don't receive any approval request notifications in Salesforce1
  or by email, even if your organization has email approval response
  enabled. However, you still receive approval request emails from a
  queue, depending on how your admin set up the queue email.

  5. Save your changes.

**When an approval request email is sent, the assigned approver and delegated approver both receive an email notification about the approval request. Delegated approvers can't reassign approval requests; they can only approve or reject approval requests.**

Comment: I am a system admin i got request to add delegated approvers for 3 users, i had add delegated approvers(namex) by editing User for the field Delegated Approver.i had done this part but i got mail from user asking that Were the approval processes also updated to allow for Delegated Approvers? how can i do it in approval process for the object promotions

Comment: You want to add delegated approvers in existing aproval process ?

Comment: yes prabhat, can i able to do this?

Comment: I am not sure about this but you can transfer existing records - Follow this link http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/103116/remove-records-from-approval-process-in-bulk/103121#103121

Comment: other link http://www.infallibletechie.com/2013/04/approvers-delegate-to-approve-record-in.html let me know if it works for you.

Comment: in infallibletechie link in the first screen shot which contains checkbox option ticked for  "The approver delegate also approve this request", i want me to do same for exisiting approval process for one object this is my requirement

Comment: where as i can able to find this option from exisiting approval process

Comment: Go to Setup > approval Process... You will get list of approval processes

Comment: Thanks prabhat, i got it now. i can able to see the option  delegated approver check box now, earlier i don't have access to edit approval steps that's why i am not able to see this option